# Want to access root database table from inside federation database in sql azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

In my application, I have created Agent and Role table in root database and split database federation according to its PK. Then I have created Customer table in federated database,So when I queried to customer. Then I have to use  this statement.

USE FEDERATION AgentFederation(AgentId='5') WITH RESET, FILTERING=OFF

Then I have to access agent name and customer role which is on root database.So how can I access root database tables inside federation database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible on Database Level (meaning queries within single connection)!

You have to do this at application level. And you can do this in parallel - execute one query over the Federation Root to get agent names and customer roles, and another query to get data from the Federation Member.

This is the only way. This is how SQL Database Federations work.